# Is there a way to separate a column with multi level structure into multiple columns with respective to the structure level?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-transform

I have an excel file in the following format, where Project/Task/Subtask are all included in a single column (e.g. AA201 = project, AA201.01 = task 01 under project AA201, and AA201.0101 = subtask 01 under task 01 under project AA201).

[original format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6oaj.png)

Is there a way to convert this into the following format using python pandas (or maybe a way to transform the data in Tableau as the data will be used as a datasource to build a dashboard), in which project/task/subtask would be in their respective columns?

[desired format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Qjq.png)

I don't even know how to word the questions correctly in order to search up on Google. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using Power Query from Excel? this will solve it quite easy

Comment: I've not used Power Query before unfortunately, is there any specific formula/function I should look up?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in python, you can read your excel file with pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('stack.xlsx') #example file 
df.head()
df['Project'].str.plit(',', expand=True)
```

This is a way to split a column.

Maybe it's easier using power query as David Leal said.

Comment: I will try this, I still don't have the actual data yet so I'm not sure what the naming convention actually is (currently assuming it's similar to the example that I provided)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Excel, but I don't think you can do it with a single formula. You need to have specific formula for each column you want to populate and taking advantage of the patterns you have in your values as you described in your question for projects having `5` characters, tasks `8` characters and subtasks `10` characters. Once you have the formulas, it should work in a general way if your values follow the same pattern.

You need to start backward from subtasks ids to project ids and then to find the corresponding descriptions.

[image: sample excel file]

### Formulas

For **Subtask** (column `I`): Identifies all the subtasks based on `ID` length

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B7, LEN(B2:B7)=10))
```

Having that, then we can populate the corresponding description (Column `J`) and drag down the formula:

```
=IF(I2="","", XLOOKUP(I2,$B$2:$B$7,$C$2:$C$7))
```

**Note**: We populate no information as empty string (`""`) in all columns.

Now for **Task** (Column `G`):

```
=VSTACK(LEFT(FILTER(I2:I20, I2:I20<>""),8), 
  FILTER(LEFT(B2:B7,8), LEN(B2:B7)=8))
```

We concatenate two arrays via `VSTACK`, to consider first task information from the subtasks and then tasks itself after.

Having this information populated we can obtain now the corresponding description (Column `H`) as follow and drag down the formula:

```
=IF(G2<>"", XLOOKUP(G2, $B$2:$B$7,$C$2:$C$7),"")
```

and finally the **Project** column (Column `E`):

```
=LET(filter, FILTER(LEFT(B2:B7,5), LEN(B2:B7)=5), 
  VSTACK(XLOOKUP(LEFT(FILTER(G2:G20, G2:G20<>""),5), filter, filter),
  filter))
```

Similarly we use `VSTACK`, to concatenate vertically first information from tasks and then information about projects it self. In your example you have only one project, but it could be more than one.

Finally the description of the projects (Column `F`)as a lookup of the **Project** column and drag down the formula:

```
=IF(E2="","", XLOOKUP(E2,$B$2:$B$7,$C$2:$C$7))
```

**Note**: All formulas are places in row `2`.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I'll prob try your suggestion of using Power Query since I'm looking for a more "automated" way of doing this. Was able to achieve a solution with Power Query but will need to make it more efficient